# Works perfect locally but on server: Failed to load resource: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, http-post, asp.net-ajax

I have a MVC5 web application which i have been working for a while. When i work on local it works perfect. But when i publish it to our company server, in a section where i print a receipt im having "Failed to load resource" error. As I said it works perfect when im working on local. Im using devexpress xtrareport .print() method to print the receipt. Here are some codes that im using:

POST method, this is the view where i get the error:

```
 function result() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        value = document.getElementById('tutar').value;
        var value3 = document.getElementById('bankalar').value;
        var value2 = parseFloat(value);
        try {
            value1 = document.getElementById('1001').innerHTML;
        } catch {
            value1 = "Girilmedi";
        }

        if (document.getElementById("musteriAdi0").value == "") {
            alert("Müşteri Adı Girilmeden İşlem Yapılamaz");
            for (var u = p; u < i; u++) {
                try {
                    var element = document.getElementById(u);
                    var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
                    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
                } catch {
                }
            }
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("HizliAlimSatim", "Kuyumcu")';
        }
        else {
            ekle();
            var m = JSON.stringify({
                'model': things, 'toplam': value2, 'personel': value1, 'KrediKarti': value3
            });
            things = [];
            $(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Kuyumcu/HizliAlimSatim",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "Json",
                    data: m,
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.includes("/Kuyumcu/Document") == false) { 
                            g = g - i;
                        } else {
                            alert("İşlem Başarılı!");
                            //window.open(data, '_blank');
                            document.getElementById('tutar').value = 0;
                            toplam = 0;
                            degistir();

                            for (var u = p; u < i; u++) {
                                try {
                                    var element = document.getElementById(u);
                                    var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
                                    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
                                } catch {
                                }
                            }
                            p = i;

                            window.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    });
}
```

this is the controller where i call print method:

```
Fis report = new Fis();
        report.Parameters["FisNo"].Value = id;
        report.Parameters["Musteri"].Value = model[0].MusteriAdSoyad;
        report.Parameters["Islemci"].Value = personel;
        report.CreateDocument(false);
        //report.ShowPreview();
        report.PrintingSystem.ShowMarginsWarning = false;
        report.Print();



        return Json(Url.Action("Document", "Kuyumcu");
```

I have been trying to solve the issue for 2 days, I thought its a server side problem but whatever i changed it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XtraReport.Print method from your controller is invoked at the server side - that's why it works when you run your application on *localhost*. When you deploy it to the production server, the Print method will be executed at the server's machine - not the client one.

Assuming that you use a [DocumentViewer](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/400221/create-end-user-reporting-applications/web-reporting/asp-net-mvc-reporting/document-viewer) to display a report on your web page, use the viewer's client-side API (see the [Print](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/js-ASPxClientWebDocumentViewer#js_ASPxClientWebDocumentViewer_Print) method) to print a report. For instance, refer to the sample code snippet from the [How to display print dialog after the WebDocumentViewer is loaded on the web page](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T558395/how-to-display-print-dialog-after-the-webdocumentviewer-is-loaded-on-the-web-page) thread.

If you want to print a report without displaying it, use the approach shown in the [following example](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/Reporting_how-to-print-export-xtrareport-in-an-aspnet-mvc-application-without-showing-a-t569785).